# Spark performance: local faster than cluster (very uneven executor load)

Tags: scala, apache-spark

let me start off by saying that I'm relatively new to spark so if I'm saying something that doesn't make sense just please correct me.

Summarising the problem, no mather what I do, at certain stages one executor does all the computation, which makes cluster execution slower than local, one-processor execution.

Full story:
I've written a spark 1.6 application which consists of series of maps, filters, joins and a short graphx part. The app uses only one data source - csv file. For the purpose of development I created a mockup dataset consisting of 100 000 rows, 7MB, with all of the fields having random data with uniform distribution (random sorting in file as well). The joins are self inner joins on PairRDD on various fields (the dataset has duplicate keys with ~200 duplicates per key immitating real data), leading to cartesian product within key. Then I perform a number of map and filter operations on the result of the joins, store it as RDD of some custom-class objects and save everything as a graph at the and.

I developed the code on my laptop and run it, which took about 5 minutes (windows machine, local file). To my surprise, when I deployed the jar onto the cluster (master yarn, cluster mode, file in csv in HDFS) and submitted it the code has taken 8 minutes to execute.
I've run same experiment with smaller data and the results were 40 seconds locally and 1.1 min on the cluster.

When I looked at history server I've seen that 2 stages are particularly long (almost 4 mins each), and on these stages there is one task that takes >90% of the time. I run the code multiple times and it was always the same task that took so much time, even though it was deployed on different data node each time.

To my surprise, when I opened the executors I saw that one executor does almost all of the job (in terms of time spent) and executes most jobs. In the screenshot provided second most 'active' executor had 50 tasks, but that's not always the case - in different submission second most busy executor had 15 tasks, and the leading one 95).
[image: Executors]

Moreover, I saw that the time of 3.9 mins is used for computation (second screenshot), which is most heavy on the joined data shortly after map. I thought, that the data may not be partitioned equally and one executor has to perform all the computation. Therefore, I tried to patrition the pairRdd manually (using .partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(40))) right before join (similar execution time) or right after join (execution even slower).
[image]

What could be the issue? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing your queries and understanding your Dataset, I'm guessing you didn't include it either because it's very complex or sensitive? So this is a little bit of a shot in the dark, however this looks a lot like a problem we dealt with on my team at work.  My rough guess at what is happening is that during one of your joins, you have a key space that has a high cardinality, but very uneven distribution. In our case, we were joining on sources of web traffic, which while we have thousands of possible sources of traffic, the overwhelming majority of the traffic comes from just a few. This caused a problem when we joined.  The keys would be distributed evenly among the executors, however since maybe 95% of the data shared maybe 3 or 4 keys, a very small number of executors were doing most of the work. When you find a join that suffers from this, the thing to do is to pick the smaller of the two datasets and explicitly perform a broadcast join. (Spark normally will try to do this, but it's not always perfect at being able to tell when it should.)

To do this, let's say you have two DataFrames. One of them has two columns, `number` and `stringRep` where number is just one row for all integers from `0-10000` and `stringRep` is just a string representation of that, so "one", "two", "three", etc. We'll call this `numToString`

The other DataFrame has some key column to join against `number` in `numToString` called `kind`, some other irrelevant data, and 100,000,000 rows. We'll call this DataFrame `ourData`. Then let's say that the distribution of the 100,000,000 rows in `ourData` is 90% have `kind == 1`, 5% have `kind == 2`, and the remaining 5% distributed pretty evenly amongst the remaining 99,998 numbers.  When you perform the following code:

```
val numToString: DataFrame = loadNumToString()
val ourData: DataFrame = loadOurCode()

val joined = ourData.join(numToString).where(ourData("kind") === numToString("number"))
```

...it is very likely that Spark will send %90 of the data (that which has `kind == 1`) to one executor, %5 of the data (that which has `kind == 2`) to another executor, and the remaining %5 smeared across the rest, leaving two executors with huge partitions and the rest with very tiny ones.

The way around this as I mentioned before is to explicitly perform a broadcast join.  What  this does is take one DataFrame and distribute it entirely to each node.  So you would do this instead:

```
val joined = ourData.join(broadcast(numToString)).where(ourData("kind") === numToString("number"))
```

...which would send `numToString` to each executor. Assuming that `ourData` was evenly partitioned beforehand, the data should remain evenly partitioned across executors. This might not be your problem, but it does sound a lot like a problem we were having. Hope it helps!

More information on broadcast joins can be found here:
https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-joins-broadcast.html

Comment: Thanks!  You pointed me into right direction - uneven data distribution. After meticulously going through my code and data I found the culprit: The data was uniform except for... "missing data" in joining columns(pairRDD key's) - empty strings, that made up 20% of the data. They were all cross joined and manipulated on one executor - the one that was slowing down the whole application. Now I have filtered them out before the join and the workload is much more even. Cheers!

Comment: So ~20% of the data was cross joining with itself?  That would do it! Glad you found the problem!